# Can I use a self-signed certificate on a live Azure cloud?

Tags: iis, deployment, https, azure, certificate

I need to test whether HTTPS works right in my Azure web role deployed on the cloud. I followed [all steps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2009/05/12/https-endpoint-on-windows-azure.aspx) to create a self-signed certificate and associate it with my role. Now my role works okay via HTTP, but requests HTTPS port just time out.

I suspect the problem is that the certificate is self-signed. Can I use self-signed certificates on a cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Phil suggests, your timeout isn't caused by your use of a self-signed certificate. You just get a security warning from your browser if the certificate isn't installed locally as a trusted Cert.

I'm using self-signed certs quite successfully.

More likely that you don't have a HTTPS Endpoint defined on port 443 (or a connectivity issue, again, as Phil suggests).

Comment: I'll accept this, the details of what was wrong are in my answer to the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732434/can-i-use-a-self-signed-certificate-on-a-live-azure-cloud/6787455#6787455

Answer (score 4):

If there is a problem with a certificate I would not expect the connection to "time out", that shoulds more like a firewall or comms issue.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem was I hadn't added the endpoint into the `<Bindings>` section in `<Sites>`:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ServiceDefinition name="RoleName" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition">
 <WebRole name="Role" vmsize="Medium">
 <Sites>
  <Site name="Web">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="HttpIn" endpointName="HttpIn" />
      <Binding name="HttpsIn" endpointName="HttpsIn" /> <<<<<<!!!!!!!
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
<ConfigurationSettings>
  blahblahblah
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

and looks like MSDN doesn't mention this explicitly at this moment of time.

So the bottom line is: self-signed certificates can be used, the browser will complain as it usually does with self-signed certificates, the new endpoint must be listed in both `<Endpoints>` and `<Bindings>`.